# how to replace values in a tensor?

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, computer-vision

I have reading an image as a tensor object, which aims to be a mask.

Now, I want to replace values which are close to white (almost 1.0) with 0 
and values which are gray to 1.

Then the mask would be correct for my machine learning task.

I have tried it with:

```
tf.where(imag >= 1.0)
```

or the next function also returns me the indices

```
greater = tf.greater_equal(mask, 0.95)
```

but how to update/assign 0? scatter_nd_add does not work for me.

```
mask = tf.scatter_nd_add(mask, greater, 0)
```

---

Edit:

I tried it differently:

```
v_mask = tf.Variable(tf.shape(mask))
ind = tf.to_float(mask >= 0.0)
v_mask.assign(ind)
```

but if I run the session. It stops there and does not go on.

What I really wanna do:
I have a gray image with the dimensions (mxnx1, tensor, float32) and the values are rescaled to from [0,255] to [0,1].

I want to replace all values which are white (1) with 0 and gray (0.45 - 0.55) with 1 and the rest should be undefined.

Answer (score 1):

To threshold your image, you can use:

```
thim = tf.tofloat(im >= 0.95) # or to whichever type you use
```

To reassign the result to `im`, *assuming* it is a variable:

```
im_update = im.assign(thim)
```

This gives you an update op that you need to call for the update to happen.

If `im` is not a variable, then you cannot reassign values to it. Generally though, cases where you really need to reassign values to a node are scarce.

Comment: it should stay a tensor

Comment: I do not get what you wanna tell me. I have an image loaded with wholeFileReader into a tensor.

Now, I want to replace all white pixels (>=0.95) with black pixels (0). How to replace those values?

Comment: Have you tried the first solution? Does it work for you? If not, what is the error?

Comment: @j35t3r I think you meant `v_mask.assign(ind)` in your last line.

Comment: @j35t3r I forgot to mention that the update op needs to be called. I updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: update = mask.assign(ind)
AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'assign'

Comment: It should be `v_mask` not  `mask`.

Comment: sry, it does not help me. Variables are only updated during sessions

Answer (score 0):

One workaround I found is to use the numpy() bridge. Do the numpy operations on the numpy array and the same is reflected in the tensor values. This is because, the numpy array and the pytorch tensor use the same underlying memory locations.

Memory sharing is mentioned on the pytorch introductory tutorial [here](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/blitz/tensor_tutorial.html#numpy-bridge)